# select rows whose sum greater than 0 using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to do, for example: Select customers whose total Sum of Amount is greater than 0. I tried below code and with reference to this result trying fetch data. but not getting Proper result.

```
    var query = (from a in saleList
                     group a by a.Cust_Ledger_Entry_No into groups
                     select groups.Sum( s => s.Amount) > 0).ToList();
```

I did above query.Now I need data which satisfying above condition.Please help me.

Comment: What are you getting in var 'query'? I mean what is the exact issue?

Comment: I need result like, customers whose sum of amount greater than 0 with all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `Where`

```
var query = from a in saleList
            group a by a.Cust_Ledger_Entry_No into g
            where g.Sum( s => s.Amount) > 0
            select new { Cust_Ledger_Entry_No = g.Key, SumAmount = g.Sum( s => s.Amount) };
```

---

> I need result like, customers whose sum of amount greater than 0
>   with all columns

If `a` is the customer and you need to select all you can use this query:

```
var query = from a in saleList
            group a by a.Cust_Ledger_Entry_No into g
            where g.Sum( s => s.Amount) > 0
            from customer in g  // flatten each group
            select customer;
```